# AngularJS and Packery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, packery

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637875/angularjs-ng-repeat-and-packery-js?answertab=active#tab-top) and the answer is perfect for me. Can help me to implement the answer in this question? Can this change be made for using `ng-repet` in codepen or somewhere? I don't know what he meant when he said to implement:

1) I had to use a directive with an event to be received by the controller

Can someone better explain how to use `nr-repeat` with `packery` in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find several working examples of Packery integration in an AngularJS app.

Here is one of them: http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/XXYwGG which works with a ng-repeat directive like the followin:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="item" style="background-color: {{item.color}};" packery></div>
```

Another codepen: http://codepen.io/gruntruk/pen/Cpewt/

or some Angular modules:

- https://github.com/SunGard-Labs/angular-packery (http://sungard-labs.github.io/angular-packery/demos/)
- https://github.com/htapal/angular-packery

Comment: I solved this, but now I have another problem, in fact, I implement packery with angular, and implement draggable also, but now I want to make in some way, system that works in such a way that when I drag and drop some tag, that make reflection on the ng-repeat array, I mean something like, https://github.com/bevacqua/angular-dragula, but on packery, do you know something about that?

Comment: This is another question to be asked: I invite you to post a new question here on SO, I think there'll be someone able to help you

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I will make a plunker with question here, thanks.